# Sticky footer with the flexible box layout model?

Tags: html, css, web

I am trying to implement a sticky footer with the flexible box layout model as implemented in recent versions of Chrome and Firefox.

Given this markup inside the body element:

```
<header>
    HEADER
</header>

<div>
    CONTENT
</div>

<footer>
    FOOTER
</footer>
```

my idea is to use the following CSS:

```
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
}

div {
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
}

footer {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

This works fine as long as the content is less than 100% of the viewport height. When the content becomes larger, however, Chrome 28 begins to paint the footer on top of the content. Is it buggy behaviour (and if: how can I workaround it) or is my CSS wrong?

You can test Chrome's behaviour here: http://jsfiddle.net/SYmJp/.

Firefox does display the thing as intended. As does Chrome/Chromium 25/26.

If this is a regression in recent Chrome versions, is the bug already reported?

**ADDED**
The apparent error persists in Chrome 29.

Comment: It's working fine here.

Comment: Interesting. I am working with Chrome 28. Now I tried Chromium 25 and, as you say, it's working fine.

Comment: I tested with Chrome 26.0.1410.64.

Comment: Can someone explain the downvote here? Even in case the reason for my question is simply a regression in Chrome, I think that knowing how to do a reliable sticky footer with the flexible box layout model is something worth to know.

Comment: Although stack overflow is a great QA site, sometimes it is unfair. Some users just downvote because they don't find any problem with the code you give. I'm voting up because I think your issue is valid.

Comment: As it may very well be just a bug in Chrome, I filed an issue: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=242034

Comment: I have this same issue in Chrome 39, but it works here: https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/

Answer (score 0):

Change height to min-height: http://jsfiddle.net/n4rv8xws/

This fixed it for me in Chrome 39:

```
html,
body {
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

I agree with your assertion that this is a Chrome regression.